# Conversion System::Uint^ to unsigned long

Tags: c++-cli

I have a function which takes pointer value as argument in my C Static Library.
    Now I am writing C/CLI wrapper on it which in turn will be used in C# code.

```
long function_C(    PULONG pulsize, PULONG pulcount );
```

Wrapper Function  C++/CLI

```
long function_Managed(  System::Uint^ size, System::Uint^ pulcount  );
```

I am calling function_C function from function_Managed.Now I facing problem to convert System::Uint^ PULONG.

My Query is
1. is this correct do this.
2. If this is correct than how to convert System::Uint^ to PULONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
long function_C(PULONG pulsize, PULONG pulcount);

int function_Managed(unsigned% size, unsigned% count)
{
    unsigned long lsize = size, lcount = count;
    long const ret = function_C(&lsize, &lcount);
    size = lsize, count = lcount;
    return ret;
}
```

To C# code, `function_Managed` will have this signature:

```cs
int function_Managed(ref uint size, ref uint count)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.stealthstartupblog.com/?p=51) for more info. Summarized below:

```
unsigned int k = *safe_cast<System::UInt^>(x);
```

Comment: I did't find anything  regarding UInt32